# How to Create Conditioned Subfolder through batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

We are using Jenkins as our CI tool. At present, I have written a batch file, which takes build value from a notepad file (written by developer), and then copies it to the network drive with the build value as a folder.

The batch file is mentioned below

```
    for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('findstr Build "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\**\build.txt"') do set Build=%%i
    set Build=%Build:'=%

if not exist "\%Build%\" mkdir "%Build%\"
```

My motive now is that, if the value in notepad is 6.1 or 6.a, i.e anything after decimal,it doesn't create folder, but places it in 6 subfolder. Alternatively, if the value is full, it creates a parent folder.

The text file, where I get the build number is mentioned below.

```
#define MyAppVersion '4.0.0.0'
#define MyFullAppVersion '4.1.0.0'
#define BuildNumber '81'
```

I need to create folder on the basis of value entered in "Build Number". If the value is in decimal, it should create within subfolder, else there should be only a main folder.

With the help of below input, I created below batch file for achieving this, but it didn't worked.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('findstr Build "C:\Folder Check\logs\build.txt"') do set Build=%%i
set Build=%Build:'=%

for /F "tokens=2""delims=." %%j in ('findstr Build "C:\Folder Check\logs\build.txt"') do set "sub=%%j"

if exist "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\" mkdir "\\network\%Build%\%sub%%"

if not exist "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\" mkdir "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\"

if exist "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\%sub%%j" XCOPY /y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\readme.txt" "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\%sub%\" /E /S

if not exist "\\172.19.0.4\Departement$\Development\Development RCX\RCX_M02_CSP\INTERNAL RELEASES\CI\%Version%\%Build%\%sub%%" XCOPY /y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\readme.txt" "\\network\%Version%\%Build%\" /E /S
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What the hell is a "notepad file"? It is a *text file*, right?

Comment: It is a text file. This is written in notepad file,#define MyAppVersion '4.0.0.0'
#define MyFullAppVersion '4.1.0.0'
#define BuildNumber '4' . By using the for command, i get the value mentioned by the developer.

Comment: Please include the text sample in your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to split off the period `.` and everything behind:

```cmd
for /F "delims=." %%j in ("%Build%") do set "Build=%%j"
```

Take also a look at the quoted `set` syntax, which is the one I recommend in general, because no special characters could cause problems that way.

Your `if exist` syntax appears a bit odd to me; I am not sure where the directory `%Build%` should be located, because you precede a `\` during existence check but you do not during creation. If you want to ensure the directory exists in the current working directory, do not precede the `\`:

```cmd
if not exist "%Build%\" mkdir "%Build%"
```

If you want it to be located in the root directory od the current drive, then do precede it by `\`, but this is not what you want, I guess.

However, the *appended* `\` is needed to check a directory for existence; not providing it would also check for files.

Anyway, to ensure a directory exists, you do not need to check for existence, you can just create it and suppress the error message that appears in case the directory already exists, like this:

```cmd
mkdir "%Build%" 2> nul
```

---

I am not sure if I interpret the `**` in your path specification right, but I assume you are going to let me know...

You can use global wild-cards (`*`, `?`) only in the *last* element of a path, so `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\**\build.txt` is not valid. In case there is only a single directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\`, you can get it like this:

```cmd
for /D %%D in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\*") do set "SubDir=%%~D"
```

If there are multiple directories and you want to get the last modified one, you could use this:

```cmd
for /F "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('
    dir /B /A:D /O:D "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\*"
') do set "SubDir=%%D"
```

Comment: ok. So now my scripts looks like for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('findstr Build "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\build.txt"') do set Build=%%i
set Build=%Build:'=%

for /F "delims=." %%j in ("%Build%") do set "Build=%%j" . I then copy my file using xcopy, and folder is created. I want to make sure that, if the value is 6,7, it creates a folder. Alternatively, if the value entered by developer is in decimal(e.g 6.5), it creates a folder in 6 directory with the name 6.5, then the copy is executed.

Comment: In general: do not change the requirements of your question as it made already available answers invalid! ask a new question instead! So basically you want an additional sub-folder `6.5` within folder `6` if `Build` holds `6.5`, but no sub-folder if `Build` holds `6`?

Comment: Yes. However above information was equally valuable.